# All Aboard the Factorio Train to Far Harad

Tags: knowledge, cipher, logic-grid, video-games

It’s been a while since you started up your Factorio game and you are trying to remember what you had done with your four trains. Use the clues below to work out which deposit each train is collecting from and how large the deposits are.
You will need access to a Tolkien book to complete this, although there’s actually more than one that would work (which is sort of a clue in itself). This is the only reason that the knowledge tag is included.

**Deposit Sizes:** 110, 170, 230, and 290 square meters.

**Deposit Ores:** iron, copper, coal, and uranium.

**Trains:** Red, blue, green, and yellow.

**Clues:**

1. The red train is collecting from a deposit 120 square meters smaller than the deposit that the blue train is collecting from.
2. The uranium deposit is __________ the one that the red train is collecting from.
3. The green train is collecting from a deposit 120 square meters ______ than the ______ deposit.
4. The ______________ trains are collecting from the copper deposit and another deposit that is 290 square meters large.
5. 1.4 2.11 3.5 9.2 14.1 8.2 3.9 7.8 12.19 2.1 8.4 5.13 3.4

[image]

Comment: Would a book from Lord of the Rings, The Hobbit, The Silmarillion, or something else work, because I don't recall any trains in J.R.R. Tolkien's books?